# Nodemon with Typescript serves stale files

Tags: typescript, nodemon, ts-node

I am using `nodemon` and `ts-node` for local development to watch for changes and reload.

Versions:

```
node: 19.0.0
nodemon: 2.0.20,
ts-node: 10.9.1
```

My run command looks like this:

```
npx nodemon application/admin/admin-rest.ts
```

This works fine unless there is already compiled `application/admin/admin-rest.js` file with **JS** extension in the same location as `admin-rest.ts` file.

In that case JS file is always served. Nodemon still detects when TS files are changed and restarts the process but content from JS file is served until I manually delete the JS file.

Comment: Make sure you configured nodemon to actually use ts-node for ts files rather than tsc

Comment: Nodemon uses `ts-node` under the hood by default in a typescript project.

Comment: Your JS files are in the same folder as your TS files? God no that's annoying. You probably want to set an `outDir` first in your tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

I use this strategy for concurrently handling typescript:

`"watch": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon --watch ./build/ --exec npm run start\"",`

[Check out this working sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/node16-concurrently-typescript-nodemon-watch-compiled-changes-88z6mf)

Here's the working code:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-nodemon-concurrently",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.ts",
    "watch": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon --watch ./build/ --exec npm run start\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Wesley LeMahieu",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node16": "^1.0.3",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

**index.ts**

```js
console.log("Hello World!");
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 16",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2021",

    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Now simply any changes made to index.ts result in `typescript compiled` changes being watched in the `build` folder.

*EDIT 1 - Keep in mind you **do not** need to install `tsc` library - just `typescript` will suffice. It's confusing since `concurrently` uses `tsc` in it's command but we don't need that library installed since typescript handles it.